# Recursive task creation results in segmentation fault in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, multitasking

I am trying to implement a nqueens solver with OpenMP, my serial code works fine but when I try to do task parallelism on that, I get segmentation fault or empty rows/cols.

Here is my implementation:

```
#define N 8
bool SOLUTION_EXISTS = false; // THIS IS GLOBAL

bool solve_NQueens(int board[N][N], int col) 
{ 

    if (col == N) 
    { 
        #pragma omp critical
            print_solution(board); 
        SOLUTION_EXISTS = true;
        return true; 
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {  
        if (can_be_placed(board, i, col) ) 
        { 
            #pragma omp taskgroup
            {   
                #pragma omp task private(col) shared(i) firstprivate(board)
                {
                    board[i][col] = 1; 
                    SOLUTION_EXISTS = solve_NQueens(board, col + 1) || SOLUTION_EXISTS; 
                    board[i][col] = 0; 
                }
            }    
        } 
    } 
    return SOLUTION_EXISTS; 
}
```

And the first call to this function is:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        solve_NQueens(board, 0);
    }
}
```

When I make col private, it gives a segmentation fault. If I do not put any variable scope, ambiguous and wrong solutions are printed.

And I am using `gcc 4.8.5`

Comment: Global variables usually spell problems, especially with recursive functions, and/or threading/parallelism.  Combining both — ouch!   I don't know OMP, so maybe I shouldn't be commenting at all, but it looks to me like you're going to have all sorts of problems with far too much shared state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

There is a segmentation fault because you use `private(col)`. Thus, `col` is not copied from your function and not even initialized. Use `firstprivate(col)` to make a proper copy of `col`.

### Advise

`omp taskgroup` will make your code run in sequential since there is an implicit barrier at the end of the scope. It is probably better to avoid it (eg. by using an `omp taskwait` at the end of the loop and changing a bit the rest of the code). 
If you want to change that, please note that `i` must be copied using a `firstprivate` rather than `shared`.

Moreover, avoid using global variables like `SOLUTION_EXISTS` in a parallel code. This generally cause a *lot* of issues from vicious bugs to slow codes. And if you still need/want to do it, the variables used in *multiple threads* must be *protected* using for example `omp atomic` or `omp critical` directives.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice but I tried your sayings and it did not work. Now, it returns no solution exists in all executions.

Comment: Hey, dude help me out, I had a huge performance slowdown. I expect some slowdown of course but not 10 times slower.